# "javascript" bar graph that breaks down annual columns to monthly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graph, charts, data-visualization

I would like the make a bar or column graph using daily data, and by default user should get annual representation of the data, then if the user clicks on a column of a specific year, they get a monthly break down of that year.

Please help
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
Also add the desire plugin to it 
<script>
window.onload = function () {

var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
    animationEnabled: true,

    title:{
        text:"Fortune 500 Companies by Country"
    },
    axisX:{
        interval: 1
    },
    axisY2:{
        interlacedColor: "rgba(1,77,101,.2)",
        gridColor: "rgba(1,77,101,.1)",
        title: "Number of Companies"
    },
    data: [{
        type: "bar",
        name: "companies",
        axisYType: "secondary",
        color: "#014D65",
        dataPoints: [
            { y: 3, label: "January" },
            { y: 7, label: "Febrary" },
            { y: 5, label: "March" },
            { y: 9, label: "April" },
            { y: 7, label: "May" },
            { y: 7, label: "June" },
            { y: 9, label: "Jult" },
            { y: 8, label: "August" },
            { y: 11, label: "September" },
            { y: 15, label: "October" },
            { y: 12, label: "November" },
            { y: 15, label: "December" },
        ]
    }]
});
chart.render();

}
</script>
```